# I got error message Unable to find a target named `YOUR_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME_HERE`, did find `FoodTracker` and `FoodTrackerTests`. how

Tags: ios, cocoapods

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FoodTracker' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FoodTracker

  target ‘FoodTrackerTests’ do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'YOUR_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME_HERE' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FoodTracker' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'    
  # Pods for FoodTracker
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
  target ‘FoodTrackerTests’ do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
```